# Downcasting Any? to UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sender

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:
        Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let card = cards[indexPath.row]
        let detailTableViewController = segue.destination as! DetailTableViewController
        detailTableViewController.card = card
        detailTableViewController.picture = card.image
    } else if segue.identifier == "addEditSegue" {
        let addEditTableViewController = segue.destination as! AddEditTableViewController
        let buttonPressed = sender as? UIBarButtonItem
        if buttonPressed == cardsAddButton {
            addEditTableViewController.isNewCard = true
        } else {
            addEditTableViewController.isNewCard = false
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, I am new to Swift. I need to perform the same segue by either tapping a UIBarButtonItem (cardsAddButton) or by tapping on cells of a UITableView. Using print statements I found that buttonPressed is nil when I tap cardsAddButton. Why? How should I check what was the sender?

Comment: You can use `if let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem { // Do your work here}`

Comment: inside the `else` put `print(sender!.description), can you post the output of that here? Just want to make sure that the class of the button is `UIBarButtonItem`

Comment: @regina_fallangi that doesn't compile. It says "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'description'"

Comment: Sorry about that. Can you try with `print(type(of: sender!))` or with `print (sender.self)`?

Comment: @regina_fallangi the first one prints  _SwiftValue, the second one prints Optional(Swift.Optional<Any>)

Comment: I was hoping that would give us the _real_ type of the sender. Sorry that did not work, but I think you should try vadian's answer. That looks like it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You – the developer – should know who the sender of `prepare(for` is. There are only three possibilities:

1. If the segue is connected to the **table view cell** in Interface Builder then the `sender` is the `UITableViewCell`.
2. If the segue is connected to the **view controller** in Interface Builder  then the `sender` is the `UIViewController`.
3. If `performSegue` is called in code then the `sender` is whatever you passed in the `sender` parameter (including `nil)`.

---

Your code can work only if you call `performSegue` in the `IBAction` of the button and pass the button instance as `sender`

```
@IBAction func addCard(_ sender : UIBarButtonItem)
{
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"addEditSegue", sender: sender)
}
```